# Send signals from Nested children widgets to ancestors in Qt (PyQT5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a window that contains two main widgets, both of which are containers of other widgets, which in turn may contain further widgets.

Each Widget is a separate class ( to maintain code readability ), and child widgets are instantiated directly inside this class, which is similar to something like React components structure.

I would like to call some methods from any widget to a top level one, or send signals from a deeply nested widget to one near top level without having to use something akin to "self.parent().parent().parent().doStuff(args)", it works but if hierarchy changes this will raise bugs, it gets harder to maintain the more complex my GUI gets.

Edit : Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve :

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central = QWidget()
        self.central.setObjectName("Central_Widget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.central)
        self.central.setStyleSheet("""
        #Central_Widget{
            background-color: #2489FF;
        }""")

        #init mainView widget
        self.leftSide = leftWindow(self.central)
        self.rightSide = rightWindow(self.central)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.leftSide)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.rightSide)

class leftWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("leftWindow")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QLabel(" Left ")
        self.leftButton = customBtn(" Left Button ", "someSVGHere", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.leftButton)

        self.setStyleSheet("border : 2px solid white;")


class rightWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("rightWindow")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QLabel(" Right ")
        self.rightButton = customBtn(" Right Button ", "someSVGHere", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.rightButton)

        self.setStyleSheet("border : 2px solid black;")


class customBtn(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text, svgIcon, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.btnText = QLabel(text)
        self.Icon = svgIcon
        layout.addWidget(self.btnText)
        # setup the icon and the stylesheet etc ....

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # if it's the right button getting clicked, change the stylesheet of the central widget in main window
        # How do I do that here ???
        return super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        

# Launcher
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.setWindowTitle("nesting test")
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above example, I want to change the background of the central widget in the MainWindow class using the right button inside the rightWindow widget, in this example it's only 2 layers of nesting so it's not really deep, but in my App I would have up to 5 or 6 layers.
ideally, each class would be in a separate file but that doesn't change this example.

I unfortunately cannot use QT designer because I'm building a modern GUI app, so every single widget will be a custom one, and I would like to keep my code fragmented instead of instantiating everything in a single class like what QT designer generates.

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried?  Just connect signals to slots as usual, right?

Comment: @G.M. I have each custom widget as it's own class, and I'm declaring widgets as class attributes so that the parent is also a container. Right now I have a home button that has a signal called sourceWidgetPressed, to connect it to "myFunction" in a top level widget I have to write `self.sourceWidgetPressed.connect(self.parentWidget().self.parentWidget().parentWidget().myFunction)`. This looks horrible IMO, I have lots of nested widgets and if the hierarchy changes this will not work, so I'm looking for a better way to implement it.

Comment: Code such as `self.sourceWidgetPressed.connect(self.parentWidget().self.parentWidget().parentWidget().myFunction)` really doesn't make much sense: why use a signal/slot rather than simply a direct function call?  It also suggests that the object referred to by `self` and the target are tightly coupled whereas one of the major benefits of the signal/slot mechanism is that it allows decoupling of signal emitters and receivers.  Before going any further you should edit your question to show some code that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @G.M. You are right, I could simply call the function directly, but I unfortunately still have to use the parentWidget() stacking call, which avoiding while it is really what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @mimminou When there is a clear hierarchy in the object structure, the [grand]children should not directly access their [gran]parent, especially so "up" in the structure. So, it would eventually be in the main widget that you actually connect the signal: `self.leftSide.leftButton.customSignal.connect(self.something)`. Note that it's also commonly suggested to create signals for each "level" and connect them by chaining the signal: create a `customSignal` for the left widget, and `self.leftButton.customSignal.connect(self.customSignal)`, then `self.leftSide.customSignal.connect(self.someting)`.

Comment: Thank you ! Your pattern is really good, even if I have lots of widgets under some class I can just get their reference descending the widget tree and connect them using a for loop, clean and concise. Would you care posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, when dealing with object hierarchy, child objects should not attempt to directly interact their parents. In fact, they should always be able to "work" on their own, no matter of their parent, and even when they have no parent at all.

Considering this, instead of connecting a signal to a slot of a [great-][grand]parent, it should be that parent that connects the [great-][grand]child signal to its own slot. This perspective is important, because it's also what allows us to connect *sibling* objects that are (nor could) be aware of each other.

```py
class customBtn(QWidget):
    customSignal = pyqtSignal(Qt.MouseButton)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.customSignal.emit(event.button())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.leftSide = leftWindow(self.central)
        self.leftSide.leftButton.customSignal.connect(self.something)

    def something(self):
        # whatever
```

If the structure has many levels, it's also good practice to create custom signals for the intermediate classes, since signals can also be *chained* as long as they have a compatible signature (the target signal must have the same argument types or *fewer* arguments with same types).

```
class leftWindow(QWidget):
    customSignal = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # ...
        self.leftButton = customBtn(" Left Button ", "someSVGHere", self)
        self.leftButton.customSignal.connect(self.customSignal)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.leftSide = leftWindow(self.central)
        self.leftSide.customSignal.connect(self.something)
```

In the case above, the signal of `leftWindow` doesn't have any arguments, so it's *compatible* with the button signal, as those arguments will be automatically discarded.

Comment: Thank you, daisy chaining signals (your answer) is the best solution I could find, Although I still think that something like React state hook could offer a cleaner way to pass data, especially for composite widgets like mine. I'll admit that I'm not sure how does QT work internally so it might not even be possible to implement, just a thought.

Comment: @mimminou I've no experience with React, but the idea of state hooks is quite similar in concept to signals. In fact, most signals are actually used for state changes of a QObject property, and you can virtually connect to an instance without knowing anything about it, thanks to the [Meta-Object system](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html). In theory, it's possible to create a "class template" (through mix-ins) that provide a meta-change system. But, in general, there's rarely such a need, and explicit signal connection (even through chaining) is quite common, immediate and with little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be best practice, but I like to implement a static signals manager class in which every custom signal is instancied. That way any QWidget can access the signals simply by importing it.

```
# module signals.py

class MainWindowSignals(QObject):
    customSignal = pyqtSignal(Qt.MouseButton)
    # otherSignal = pyqtSignal(...)

class SignalsManager:
    mainwindow = MainWindowSignals()
```

then in your code :

```
from signals import SignalsManager

class CustomBtn(QWidget):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        SignalsManager.mainwindow.customSignal.emit(event.button())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        SignalsManager.mainwindow.customSignal.connect(self.something)

    def something(self):
        # whatever
```

Hope this helps anyone currently experimenting with PyQt6.